# Writing custom routes for sails js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I am building a blogging application to compliment my wordpress installation and i have links that look like this

```
http://localhost:1337/noder/notbye/56677/to/677888
```

which i am using to get all posts between id `56677` to id `677888`

My controller is called `noder` and id `56677` to id `677888`

This is my controller action

```
notbye: function (req, res) {
      var u = 'lorem ipsum';
    res.send(u);
  }
```

and this is my custom route

```
'get /noder/:id/to/:nextid' : 'NoderController.notbye',
```

When i visit this page `http://localhost:1337/noder/notbye/56677/to/677888`

i get a `404`

How can i correct my route and controller to be able to visit `http://localhost:1337/noder/notbye/56677/to/677888` without any problem?.

Comment: Why the downvote,the docs section on routes aren't very clear and there are hardly any examples with custom routes. All the examples i have seen strangely tend to dwell on the blueprint api.

Comment: verify the conf in blueprint, i use action, shorcut and rest as false.  and in routes:   'get /users/:username': {
    controller: 'NoderController',
    action    : 'notbye'
  },

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way.

For this link

```
http://localhost:1337/noder/notbye/56677/to/889999
```

i have this `controller`

```
notbye: function (req, res,next) {
      var u = 'lorem ipsum';
      var x = req.params.to;
    res.send(x);
  }
```

and this is my router code

```
'get /noder/notbye/:id/:to/:nextid' : 'NoderController.notbye',
```

I hope that helps someone on the sails routing section.